# Show Random Background IMage

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, background

I have an element with a background image, is it possible to change that background image to a random image URL that I have?

So when a user loads the page, a random background image will be show.

## Update

---

Thanks everyone who answered my question, you're all awesome!

Comment: One more variant: http://jsfiddle.net/EyKZZ/

Comment: @VisioN After changing the background images on the JSFiddle, it's no longer working. Why's that?!

Comment: It should work by all means. Possibly it shows image randomized in the previous run.

Comment: @VisioN It works now although the background image is repeated. I'm looking to make the background image stretched the whole width and height. I have body { width: 100%; height: 100%; } although the background image is repeat.

Comment: @VisioN Nice pictures! lol. Now on to Jamie Brittain: Do you mean that you want the image to be stretched (and possibly distorted) in order to fill the background? I don't think that's possible to do to a background using css, but as a workaround, you could just make it a picture behind everything else with position: absolute, that way you can apply the height and width: 100% css modifications.

Comment: @Grezzo, possible in CSS3. Thanks, I also enjoy cats :)

Comment: So it is! So I'm guessing you want something like background-size: 100% 100%;

Comment: @Grezzo Yeh, having it stretched is fine. I don't mind using an the <img> tag although I thought it was easier to be using background-image when it comes to change the background-image instead of the <img> source on page load.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Here is an example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").css("background-image", "url("+your_random_image_url+")");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Name you image files as "image1.jpg" "image2.jpg" and so on. Generate a random number

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*range_of_your_image_nums+1);
```

Then use this number to load your random image as

```
$("#id_of_your_element").css("background","<url>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Sample Script that does it, below is the way I do it. Tested with IE 6 and Firefox (2 and 3).
The background image is fixed on the right site and will not scroll.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeImg(imgNumber) {
var myImages = ["images/image0.jpg", "images/image1.jpg", "images/image2.jpg", "images/image3.jpg"];
var imgShown = document.body.style.backgroundImage;
var newImgNumber =Math.floor(Math.random()*myImages.length);
document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+myImages[newImgNumber]+')';
}
window.onload=changeImg;
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.bg {background-attachment:fixed; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position:top right;}
</style>
</head>
<body class="bg">
<p>Some text</p>
<!-- put a lot text lines here to see that the background stays fixed. -->
<p>Some text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep an array with all your backgrounds, and load a random one at `$(document).ready()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var backgrounds = ['link1', ..., 'linkN'];
    $("#yourElementId").css("background-image: url("+backgrounds[Math.round(Math.random() * (backgrounds.length - 1))] +")");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var backgrounds = ['',
                   'bg3.jpg',
                   'bg1.jpg',
                   'bg1013.jpg',
                   'bg123.gif',
                   'bg553.jpg',
                   'bg663.png',
                   'bgdaas3.jpg',
                   'bgdw3.jpg',
                   'bgdd3.jpg',
                   'dasd.png'
                  ];

$('#elementID').css('background', 'url('+backgrounds[Math.random()*10]+')');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var images = ["the-nude-art.jpg", "the-secret-pic.jpg","topless-pic.png","oolala-pic.jpg"]; 
    var rand_image = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];
    var my_site_image_folder_path  = 'http://www.xyz.com/images/';
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url("' + my_site_image_folder_path + rand_image + '")');
});
```